# PUT a file in Tika but without curl

Tags: php, curl, apache-tika

So far, I have seen numerous examples on how to PUT a file in a Tika server using curl. For example from the Tika wikipage documentation we can conclude that if your file is in location

```
"file:///var/www/html/files/a.pdf"
```

in your machine and the Tika server runs on

```
http://localhost:9998
```

then using curl you can do a

```
curl -s "file:///var/www/html/files/a.pdf" | curl -X PUT -T - http://localhost:9998/meta
```

to get the metadata.

However, I haven't seen an example where the complete URI is given that makes the above JAXRS tika server providing the same result as the curl command above but showing the result in my browser this time and not on the terminal.

So, say I am visiting on my browser the tika server URI:

```
http://localhost:9998
```

what do I have to append to this URI in order to get the metadata like the curl command in my browser?

Thank you forum

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the curl command in your question:

```
curl -s "file:///var/www/html/files/a.pdf" | curl -X PUT -T - http://localhost:9998/meta
```

The URL you need to put to is at the end - `http://localhost:9998/meta`

You can also find all the endpoints in a Tika server from the listing linked from the welcome page when you go to the server with your web browser, and from [Tika Wika Page for the Server](http://wiki.apache.org/tika/TikaJAXRS)

Comment: So just to verify that I got it right, your answer Gagravarr is                                                                                                                                                                                    that the constructed link I should append to my browser bar is this:  http://localhost:9998/meta/file:///var/www/html/files/a.pdf      ?  Cause when I click on the link nothing shows in my browser. Remember I do not want to use curl, cause when I do, all the metadata is spit on my terminal, whereas when I click on the above constructed link I get nothing

Comment: You can't do anything like that. You need to PUT your resource to `http://localhost:9998/meta`, using whatever you want - curl, javascript, php code snippet, html form etc. You can't just do it with a magic url in a browser